# What are the advantages to using count sort in this algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, grouping

Working on following algorithm:

> You are given an array of student objects. Ever student has an integer-valued age field that is to be treated as a key. Rearrange the elements of the array so that students of equal age appear together. The order in which different ages appear is not important. How would your solution change if ages have to appear in sorted order?

The author solution of the book the problem comes from says to create two hashes - one that maps age => number of occurrences of that age, and another that maps age to the offset in the final array. Then, iterate over these two hashes and write the values with appropriate offsets in the final array.

Author code:

```
import collections 
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', ('age', 'name'))

def group_by_age(people):
  age_to_count = collections.counter([person.age for person in people])
  age_to_offset, offset = {}, 0 

  for age, count in age_to_count.items():
    age_to_offset[age] = offset 
    offset += count  

  while age_to_offset: 
    from_age = next(iter(age_to_offset))
    from_idx = age_to_offset[from_age]
    to_age = people[from_idx].age
    to_idx = age_to_offset[people[from_idx].age]
    people[from_idx], people[to_idx] = people[to_idx], people[from_idx]

    age_to_count[to_age] -= 1

    if age_to_count[to_age]:
      age_to_offset[to_age] = to_idx + 1 
    else:
      del age_to_offset[to_age]
```

I'm wondering why we can't simplify things, and just create a hash with key = age and value = object. Then just iterate over hash keys and write the values to the array. If need to sort output, can sort hash keys and key in to hash to write values to input array.

**Question 1:** Why did the author go with a less intuitive route?

**Question 2**: Is my code below (based off author solution) as good? This code is much cleaner, which begs the question why the author didn't go with this route.

```
import collections 
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', ('age', 'tuple'))

def group_ages(people):
  age_to_count = collections.Counter([person.age for person in people])

  age_to_offset, offset = {}, 0 

  for age, count in age_to_count.items():
    age_to_offset[age] = offset 
    offset += count  

  for old_index, person in enumerate(people):
    new_index = age_to_offset[person.age]
    people[old_index], people[new_index] = people[new_index], people[old_index]

    age_to_count[person.age] -= 1

    if age_to_count[person.age]:
      age_to_offset[person.age] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its right, that you can sort the hash `keys` and print them in order, but then how will you remember the `keys`.

For e.g. lets say you have 3 students with ages 20,40 and 15.
Now in `hashmap`, they will something be like, `h[20]="",h[40]="",h[15]=""`.

But after sorting them, how will you print values from `h`. You wont be having indices now. 
And if you try to get the keys from main `array`, you will again use some other sort for that.